# Css Hover and space between element

Tags: html, css, hover

I try to have a div that appears on hover, but when a put a space (margin) between the hovered line and the showed element **my hover state disappears when my pointer is in between the two div.**

```css
#dropdown {
    text-align: center;
}  

#dropdown .sub-menu{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#dropdown:hover .sub-menu{
    visibility: visible;
}



#dropdown .sub-menu ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="menu-user-titre"> 
    <span>Hover me</span>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">hello</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I keep the space and the hover ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you should **remove** this line of **#dropdown .sub-menu**:

```
margin-top: 30px;
```

and **add** this:

```
#menu-title{
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

padding is subset of #mwnu-title element.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="dropdown">
        <div id="menu-title"> 
            <span>Hover me</span>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">hello</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**style:**

```
#dropdown {
    text-align: center;
}


#dropdown .sub-menu{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 250px;
    
}

#dropdown:hover .sub-menu{
    visibility: visible;
}





/* OTHER */

#dropdown .sub-menu ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}

#menu-title{
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```